# Test case scenarios of import excel feature in web application?

Tags: testing

I am a Quality Analyst. Performing testing on a web application. So in my web application, there is one button of "Import excel". Through which we can import some records of user like Email Id, Mobile No, Name, etc. So as I am a beginner I want test cases scenarios for testing that import excel feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try out the following scenarios:

- Check different file (Other Then Excel)
- Small/Large size file
- Enter all the records Email id, Mobile, No and name and then leave one row empty and check the behavior of the system.
- Make sure that on uploading empty file, error message should be displayed.
- Make sure that multiple users can at a time perform the upload process.
- Make sure that empty spaces in between the uploaded content is not displayed in the corresponding listing page.
- Make sure that on trying to upload already existing data, proper notification message is displayed.